# How to proceed if you don't have enough reputation for placing a comment

Tags: discussion

I just ran into a question to which I need further information to answer it correctly. Since I can't post a comment due to insufficient reputation I'm wondering how I can get the user to rephrase the question?

In other words I can't understand why you need 50 reputation points to comment.

Comment: 50 rep really isn't that hard to get - you're most of the way there.  You also have at least 20 rep, so you could pop into [Server Fault Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) and ask one of the folks there to leave a comment for you if it's really urgent though...

Answer (score 14):

I think the only answer is:  You earn the requisite reputation, then post the comment.

Users who flout this convention (by posting a comment as an answer or editing existing posts) will usually have their posts flagged or edits declined.  Site moderators must then take the time to process said flags.  This is not an efficient use of other's time.

Requests to lower the comment-rep-requirement have been declined by the StackExchange team.  See this meta.SO question as an example: [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

Here is a full [list of reputation privileges](https://serverfault.com/privileges) -- 50 rep is not a terribly difficult milestone to reach.  Even just *asking* questions earns you rep.

Comment: It's also worth noting how trivial it is: posts you make [while your rep is below 10](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136195/206620) have visibility in the "new posts" review hopper. This not only makes it very easy to get a large amount of rep for your first good answer, but also offers a measure of forgiveness if you were too fast on the draw to post before reading all of the rules.

Answer (score 9):

Alternate answer: Post to meta. Wait for others to lurk your profile on the main site. Garner up votes, thus enabling you to comment site-wide.

Well played sir. :)